# Displaying image link as image stored in mongodb in the ejs file

Tags: mongodb, image, hyperlink, ejs

Lets say i have an image link that is stored in mongodb as a string. The image is uploaded somewhere and is accessible. How would i be able to display this thing that holds the string as an image in the ejs or html page?

For example the schema is: User.

And the name that holds the string in the database = user.characterimg

However if i would put that just like that in a ejs file it would only show the string and not the actual image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:
src= <%=user.characterimg%>>